# Sum Of Functions in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to curve fit an arbitrary sum of distributed gaussians to a function -- each with their own set of parameters. Currently, if I want to use twenty functions, I do the following

```
φ[α_?NumberQ, x_?NumberQ, xi_?NumberQ, c_?NumberQ] := (
  c E^(- α (x - xi)^2/2))/Sqrt[α/π];
Data := Table[{n/50, N[f[n/50]]}, {n, -300, 300}];

model = φ[a1, x, x1, c1] + φ[a2, x, x2, c2] + φ[a3, x, x3, c3] + 
   φ[a4, x, x4, c4] + φ[a5, x, x5, c5] + φ[a6, x, x6, c6] + 
   φ[a7, x, x7, c7] + φ[a8, x, x8, c8] + φ[a9, x, x9, c9] + 
   φ[a10, x, x10, c10] + φ[a11, x, x11, c11] + φ[a12, x, x12, c12] + 
   φ[a13, x, x13, c13] + φ[a14, x, x14, c14] + φ[a15, x, x15, c15] + 
   φ[a16, x, x16, c16] + φ[a17, x, x17, c17] + φ[a18, x, x18, c18] + 
   φ[a19, x, x19, c19] + φ[a20, x, x20, c20];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[Data, 
   model, {a1, x1, c1, a2, x2, c2, a3, x3, c3, a4, x4, c4, a5, x5, c5, a6, x6,
     c6, a7, x7, c7, a8, x8, c8, a9, x9, c9, a10, x10, c10, a11, x11, c11, 
     a12, x12, c12, a13, x13, c13, a14, x14, c14, a15, x15, c15, a16, x16, c16,
     a17, x17, c17, a18, x18, c18, a19, x19, c19, a20, x20, c20}, x];
```

This works well but it is tedious to create these linear combinations by hand. It would be wonderful to create a linear combination of functions with a vector of coefficients for a, xi, and c. I am just unsure of how to approach this and I was hoping that you guys could offer some insight into this.

Best,

Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did something just like this before:

```
params = Flatten[
   Table[{Subscript[a, i], Subscript[m, i], Subscript[c, i]}, {i, 1, 
     n}]];
model = Sum[
   Phi[Subscript[a, i], x, Subscript[m, i], Subscript[c, i]], {i, 1, 
    n}];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, params, x]];
```

Just replace n with however many Gaussians you need. Obviously if you have different basis functions you'll have to do other things, but this works nicely when you're working just a set of (or even two) basis functions.

Here's some proof of concept code:

```
Phi[x_, a_, b_, c_] := c Exp[-(x - a)^2/b^2]/(b Sqrt[\[Pi]])

n = 10;
Ap = RandomReal[{-5, +5}, {n}];
Bp = RandomReal[{0.2, 2}, {n}];
Cp = RandomReal[{-3, +3}, {n}];
f[x_] := Evaluate[Sum[Phi[x, Ap[[i]], Bp[[i]], Cp[[i]]], {i, n}]]

data = Module[{x, y},
   x = RandomReal[{-10, +10}, {3000}];
   y = f[x];
   Transpose[{x, y}]];
(* Force data to be precision to be 50 digits, so we can use higher precision in NLMF *)
data = N[Round[data * 10^50] / 10^50, 50];


params = Flatten@Table[{a@i, b@i, c@i}, {i, n}];
model = Sum[Phi[x, a@i, b@i, c@i], {i, n}];
fit = Normal@NonlinearModelFit[data, model, params, x, WorkingPrecision->50];

Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[fit, {x, -5, +5}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: I think you somehow mixed up `f` and `Phi`

Comment: Yeah I did. I tried doing `FindFit` and apparently `FindFit` can get the same kind of fit as `NonlinearModelFit`, so I removed that from the answer. I suppose that's to be expected that `NonlinearModelFit` is more generalized.

Comment: @Mike, I ran a modification of the above code (http://pastebin.com/Xwmn18UT) And I got the following error: LinearAlgebra`BLAS`TRSV::oflow: Machine overflow encountered during computations but only for 22 basis functions or more. Do you have ant advice for how to properly deal with this?

Comment: @Thomas: Have you tried increasing the precision of the computation? I'll add a modification that demonstrates how to do this.

Comment: @Thomas: Overflows could also be due to the large number of basis functions. It's possible that one of the fits it tries as it optimizes the parameters is producing results that are too large to represent. In that case, you may have to reduce the number of basis functions or increase the accuracy and precision of the computation.

Comment: @Mike It appears that increasing the working precision didn't help so I think I need to use fewer basis functions. Regardless, thank you for your help. You're a life saver. If I wanted to put a citation in my mathematica notebook (and consequently, an acknowledgement in a paper), what would I list your affiliation as?

Comment: @Thomas, no problem. That's what this site is designed for :) Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm affiliated with Hofstra Uiversity.

Answer (score 4):

You may try:

```
Phi[α_, x_, xi_, c_] := (c E^(- α (x - xi)^2/2))/Sqrt[α/π];

model = Sum[Phi[a@i, x, xx@i, c@i], {i, 20}];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[Data, model, Flatten@Table[{a@i, xx@i, c@i}, {i, 20}], x]
```

**Edit**

Not tested, but I think for leaving the number of Gaussians indeternate you could also do something like:

```
nlm[n_] := NonlinearModelFit[Data, Sum[Phi[a@i, x, xx@i, c@i], {i, n}]
                                   Flatten@Table[{a@i, xx@i, c@i}, {i, n}], x];

nlm[20]
```

Comment: You're missing an x in there at the end. I like how we ended up posting almost the same exact thing.

Comment: @belisarius Wow, this works brilliantly! Thank you! I absolutely missed the Flatten command, wow.